# downstream rate limiting, how to deal with it

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

the intention is to build a proxy yet to 'stuff' some business logic, however the downstream has a rate limiting (daily x million of msgs AND y number of concurrent connections), how to achieve this easily in the combination of ipaas service offerings (apim+loigic app+service bus)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Service Bus queue to store the messages, then you can use a function with limited concurrency or a Logic App to forward to the downstream system.

That way Service Bus handles the throughput spikes and concurrency spikes.

Comment: Thanks David! Any thought how to “aggregate” the individual msgs from queue so the function can call the downstream in batches rather to work more efficiently

Comment: You could use a logic app with a batch trigger to aggregate messages

Comment: Ditto on a Function.  But if one message in a batch should fail, error handling is trickier with batching.